# How can I select a value from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I select a value from an array? Example is this `String[] ans = {"+", "-", "/", "*"};` then I want to select `"+"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] ans = {"+","-","/","*"};
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner calcu = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter First number: ");
    numOne = calcu.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Second number: ");
    numTwo = calcu.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose an Operator to use");

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ans[0]` for "+" and so on.

```
ans[0] = "+";
ans[1] = "-";
ans[2] = "/";
ans[3] ="*";
```

In your case, this code will help you:

```
     public static void main(String[] a) {

        String[] ans = {"+","-","/","*"};
        double result = 0;
        Scanner calcu = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter First number: ");
        int numOne = calcu.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Second number: ");
        int numTwo = calcu.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Choose an Operator to use");
        String oparation= calcu.next();

        if(oparation.equals(ans[0])){
           result = numOne + numTwo;
        }
        else if(oparation.equals(ans[1])){
            result = numOne - numTwo;
        }
        else if(oparation.equals(ans[2])){
            result = numOne / numTwo;

        } else if(oparation.equals(ans[3])){
            result = numOne * numTwo;
        }
        System.out.println("result is " + result);

   }
```

If you want same result using a `switch` statement:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {

        double result = 0;
        Scanner calcu = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter First number: ");
        int numOne = calcu.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Second number: ");
        int numTwo = calcu.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Choose an Operator to use");
        String oparation= calcu.next();

        switch(oparation){
            case "+" :
            result = numOne + numTwo;
            break;

            case "-" :
            result = numOne - numTwo;
            break;

            case "/" :
            result = numOne / numTwo;
            break;

            case "*" :
            result = numOne * numTwo;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("result is " + result);

   }
```

However, with the `switch` statement, if you want to compare against variables like `case ans[0]:` instead of `case "*"`, then you can use `enum`.

Comment: What can I do if I want the user to select "-" operator using scanner inputs? please help I'm newbie to java. :(

Comment: @AngelaVinagrera  you need to use if condition to check that

Comment: @AngelaVinagrera  what would you expect to input user when you say "Choose an Operator to use" ?do user input 1,2,3,4 to choose operator or - +,-,/,*

Comment: users will input  - +,-,/,* operator according to their choices.

Answer (score 3):

The way you're implementing it, you would need to display a list like this to the user:

```
1: +
2: -
3: /
4: *
```

When they select a number, you can determine the operator with `ans[input-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it via **get** method like this:

```
ans[i]; // for getting first element you should set i to 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`ans[indexThatYouWantToaccess]` make sure array index starts with 0

```
ans[0] -> +
ans[1] -> -
ans[2] -> /
ans[3] -> *
```

Answer (score 3):

To reference single items in the array, use brackets with the position of the item you want to reference, starting with 0.

so

`string txt = ans[0];` would yield `+`

and `string txt = ans[2];` would yield `/`

Answer (score 3):

You have the array as `String[] ans = {"+","-","/","*"};` that means the index of the array from `zero` to `array.length-1` contains the element you inserted into the array so for getting the element out of the array just iterate the array or simply get the element by the index of the array

```
for(String value : ans){
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<ans.length-1;i++){
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
        }
```

or
simple

```
String value = ans[index];//index must be from 0 to arrayLength-1
System.out.println("value "+value);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ans[0]` will return the first(0 because the first element starts with 0, not 1) element of the array, `ans[1]` the second and so on..

Answer (score 2):

You select a value from an array by referring to the index of its element.  Array elements (the things inside your array), are numbered/indexed from 0 to length-1 of your array.

In this case, if you want to first element of your array you'd do:

```
ans[0]
```

If you want the last element of your array:

```
ans[ans.length-1]
```

Have a look at this guide for a great intro to Arrays.
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Arrays/arrays.html